# How to add new column from list column value

Tags: r

How to unlist list column and add new column from unlist column value in data frame.Can you please find my df below.

My data Frame.

```
Status       AuditResult                                               Deship                                        Item

Active    list(DDID=c("2","First"),Dvalue=c("Bpin","67"))  list(UserID=1,Add="Stet,Bpin")  list(Menu=1,Bill=9,Deship =list(list(IDesc ="A",vendor=5)))

Inactive  list(DDID=c("Second","8"),Dvalue=c("CA","98"))   list(UserID=2,Add="Stet,Bpin")  list(Menu=1,Bill=8,Deship =list(list(IDesc ="B,N,O",vendor=4)))

OnHold    list(DDID=c("78","8",NA),Dvalue=c("UK","76"))   list(UserID=1,Add="Stet,Bpin")  list(Menu=1,Bill=7,Deship =list(list(IDesc ="L,q",vendor=2)))
```

Expected data frame.

```
Status   DDID          Dvalue         UserID    Add         Menu  Bill  IDesc    vendor

Active   "2","First"   "Bpin","67"    1       "Stet,Bpin"    1     9     "A"        5

Inactive "Second","8"  "CA","98"      2       "Stet,Bpin"    1     8     "B,N,O"    4

OnHold   "78","8",NA   "UK","76"      1       "Stet,Bpin"    1     7     "L,q"      2
```

please suggest me if any unstructured code.

Dput.

```
structure(list(Status = c("Active", "Inactive", "OnHold"), AuditResult = list(
    structure(list(DDID = c(2, "First"), Dvalue = c("Bpin", 
    67)), .Names = c("DDID", "Dvalue"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    structure(list(DDID = c("Second", 8), Dvalue = c("CA", 
    98)), .Names = c("DDID", "Dvalue"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    structure(list(DDID = c("78","8",NA), Dvalue = c("UK", 
    76)), .Names = c("DDID", "Dvalue"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), 
    Deship = list(structure(list(UserID = 1, Add = "Stet, Bpin"), .Names = c("UserID", 
    "Add"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        UserID = 2, Add = "Stet, Bpin"), .Names = c("UserID", 
    "Add"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        UserID = 1, Add = "Stet, Bpin"), .Names = c("UserID", 
    "Add"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), Item = list(
structure(list(Menu = 1, Bill = 9.0, Deship = list(
            structure(list(IDesc = "A", vendor = 5), .Names = c("IDesc", 
            "vendor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Menu", 
        "Bill", "Deship"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(Menu = 1, Bill = 8.0, Deship = list(
            structure(list(IDesc = "B,N,O", vendor = 4), .Names = c("IDesc", 
            "vendor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Menu", 
        "Bill", "Deship"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(Menu = 1, Bill = 7.0, Deship = list(
            structure(list(IDesc = "L,q", vendor = 2), .Names = c("IDesc", 
            "vendor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Menu", 
        "Bill", "Deship"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Status", 
"AuditResult", "Deship", "Item"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each of the list columns has a different structure, you'll have to deal with them in different ways.

With base R:

```
dfnew <- data.frame(df$Status,
                    do.call(rbind, lapply(df$AuditResult, function(x) sapply(x, toString))),
                    do.call(rbind, df$Deship),
                    do.call(rbind, lapply(df$Item, unlist)))
names(dfnew) <- sub('^.*\\.','',names(dfnew))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dfnew
>     Status      DDID   Dvalue UserID        Add Menu Bill IDesc vendor
> 1   Active  2, First Bpin, 67      1 Stet, Bpin    1    9     A      5
> 2 Inactive Second, 8   CA, 98      2 Stet, Bpin    1    8 B,N,O      4
> 3   OnHold 78, 8, NA   UK, 76      1 Stet, Bpin    1    7   L,q      2
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response,above code is working fine ,but you have hardcoded data frame  header Name.is there any way to do dynamically by checking is column is "List".

Comment: @udya `sapply(df, class)` or `sapply(df, is.list)`

Comment: ,Thank you so much,at the same time i facing one problem, special charactor(#) and space are replaced as (.).Because in my real time list data i have dup history address and  emp#.But it replace dup.history.address and  emp.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the name of your data frame is called `dt`, here is an option.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  select(Status, AuditResult) %>%
  mutate(DDID = map(AuditResult, ~.$DDID),
         Dvalue = map(AuditResult, ~.$Dvalue)) %>%
  mutate(DDID = map_chr(DDID, ~toString(.)),
         Dvalue = map_chr(Dvalue, ~toString(.))) %>%
  select(-AuditResult)

dt3 <- dt %>%
  select(Status, Deship) %>%
  unnest()

dt4 <- dt %>%
  select(Status, Item) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  unnest()

dt_final <- reduce(list(dt2, dt3, dt4), left_join, by = "Status")
dt_final
#     Status      DDID   Dvalue UserID        Add Menu Bill IDesc vendor
# 1   Active  2, First Bpin, 67      1 Stet, Bpin    1    9     A      5
# 2 Inactive Second, 8   CA, 98      2 Stet, Bpin    1    8 B,N,O      4
# 3   OnHold 78, 8, NA   UK, 76      1 Stet, Bpin    1    7   L,q      2
```

Comment: ,Thanks for response ,its working fine,but DDID,Dvalue column class is return "list" is there any chance to change its as character.Because further doing some grouping operation that one not support "list" type.

Comment: @udya Please see my update. Now `DDID` and `Dvalue` are character columns.

Comment: @udya I am glad it helps. Please accept my answer if it is helpful.

Comment: ,i have one more doubt in my above post i have only three list of column .but real time data frame will have more than 50 list of column every list of column have more than 15 value .i'm not suppose to add ever column manually.is there any way to add column name dynamically.

Comment: @udya If all lists have a different structure, it would be hard to automatic add column names. See if Jaap's answer is helpful.